# Debugging Wifi connection issues on Mac OS X

Tags: wireless-networking

I'm attempting to debug a wifi connection issue I'm having on Mac OS X. I ran Mac's Wireless Diagnostics tool and generated the following for the wifi network of interest.

```
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
Timestamp    Name                          Duration    Result    Description                            
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
Hidden Wi-Fi Scan Results                  0.016       Yes       13:08:48.387        Found 14 hidden network(s)
Conflicting Wi-Fi CC                       0.001       Yes       13:08:48.386        Found conflicting country code(s) (us)
                                                                                     'eufy RoboVac 30C-D1CE' — 86:f3:eb:de:d1:ce (CN)
HT40 2.4GHz Networks                       0.019       Yes       13:08:48.366        Found HT40 network(s) in 2.4GHz
                                                                                     'SpectrumSetup-A8' — 5a:5b:3b:43:e4:a6 (ch 6)
                                                                                     'MySpectrumWiFi6E-2G' — c8:b4:22:e1:13:6c (ch 11)
Congested Wi-Fi Channel                    0.014       Yes       13:08:48.351        Current channel (44) is congested
                                                                                     Recommended 2.4GHz — 1
                                                                                     Recommended 5GHz — 161
Large PNL                                  0.004       Yes       13:08:48.337        Wi-Fi PNL count (35)
AirPort Base Station                       0.001       No        13:08:48.331        Current network is not an AirPort Base Station
Uncommon DTIM Interval                     0.001       Yes       13:08:48.321        DTIM interval is 0ms
AWDL Enabled                               0.000       Yes       13:08:48.317        AWDL is active
BT Paired Count                            0.061       Yes       13:08:48.255        Paired Bluetooth device count (5)
Primary IPv6 is Wi-Fi                      0.000       No        13:08:48.254        None
Primary IPv4 is Wi-Fi                      0.000       No        13:08:48.253        None
IPv6 Assigned                              0.000       No        13:08:48.252        Wi-Fi does not have IPv6 assigned
IPv4 Assigned                              0.006       No        13:08:48.246        Wi-Fi does not have IPv4 assigned
Curl Apple                                 0.009       No        13:08:48.220        Could not curl 'https://captive.apple.com'
Reach Apple                                0.000       No        13:08:48.220        Could not reach 'www.apple.com'
Resolve DNS                                0.001       No        13:08:48.218        Could not resolve 'captive.apple.com'
Ping LAN                                   0.000       No        13:08:45.005        Could not ping router ((null) / 0.00ms / BE / 64 bytes / i=0.000000s / W=0.000000s t=0.000000s / c=0)
Ping WAN                                   0.000       No        13:08:45.002        Could not ping DNS server ((null) / 0.00ms / BE / 64 bytes / i=0.000000s / W=0.000000s / t=0.000000s / c=0)
Reach Apple                                0.000       No        13:08:16.762        Could not reach 'www.apple.com'
Resolve DNS                                0.001       No        13:08:16.762        Could not resolve 'captive.apple.com'
Ping WAN                                   0.006       No        13:08:16.762        Could not ping DNS server ((null) / 0.00ms / BE / 64 bytes / i=0.000000s / W=0.000000s / t=0.000000s / c=0)
Ping LAN                                   0.007       No        13:08:16.762        Could not ping router ((null) / 0.00ms / BE / 64 bytes / i=0.000000s / W=0.000000s t=0.000000s / c=0)
Ping LAN                                   0.007       No        13:08:16.762        Could not ping router ((null) / 0.00ms / BE / 64 bytes / i=0.000000s / W=0.000000s t=0.000000s / c=0)
Ping LAN                                   0.007       No        13:08:16.762        Could not ping router ((null) / 0.00ms / BE / 64 bytes / i=0.000000s / W=0.000000s t=0.000000s / c=0)
Ping LAN                                   0.008       No        13:08:16.762        Could not ping router ((null) / 0.00ms / BE / 64 bytes / i=0.000000s / W=0.000000s t=0.000000s / c=0)
Ping LAN                                   0.008       No        13:08:16.762        Could not ping router ((null) / 0.00ms / BE / 64 bytes / i=0.000000s / W=0.000000s t=0.000000s / c=0)
Ping LAN                                   0.008       No        13:08:16.762        Could not ping router ((null) / 0.00ms / BE / 64 bytes / i=0.000000s / W=0.000000s t=0.000000s / c=0)
Ping LAN                                   0.008       No        13:08:16.762        Could not ping router ((null) / 0.00ms / BE / 64 bytes / i=0.000000s / W=0.000000s t=0.000000s / c=0)
Ping LAN                                   0.008       No        13:08:16.762        Could not ping router ((null) / 0.00ms / BE / 64 bytes / i=0.000000s / W=0.000000s t=0.000000s / c=0)
Curl Apple                                 0.019       No        13:08:16.762        Could not curl 'https://captive.apple.com'
Ping6 AWDL                                 0.022       Yes       13:08:16.762        Could ping AWDL (ff02::fb / 0.10ms / BE / 74 bytes / w=1.000000s / c=1)
Ping WAN                                   1.008       No        13:08:16.762        Could not ping DNS server (17.254.0.22 / 0.00ms / BE / 68 bytes / i=0.100000s / W=1.600000s / t=1.600000s / c=1)
Retrieve Apple Over WiFi                   0.008       No        13:08:01.982        Could not retrieve 'https://captive.apple.com' over Wi-Fi
Ping WAN (CFNetwork)                       0.000       No        13:08:01.960        Could not ping DNS server ((null) / 0.00ms / BE / 64 bytes / i=0.000000s / W=0.000000s / t=0.000000s / c=0)
Ping LAN (CFNetwork)                       0.006       No        13:08:01.954        Could not ping router ((null) / 0.00ms / BE / 64 bytes / i=0.000000s / W=0.000000s t=0.000000s / c=0)
```

Does anyone understand what any of this means? How should I proceed? Note that this is not my personal router but rather a wifi network in my apartment building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem it shows is that you're not getting an IP address assigned, and so every test after that, that requires an IP address, is failing.

You'll need to figure out why you're not getting an IP address assigned. For example, do you expect that network to contain a DHCP server that serves out IPv4 address leases? Can you confirm that that DHCP server is up and running and is reachable from the AP your client was associated to?